# iPhone 5 tethering, device hard to discover, normal or a problem?

Tags: wifi, iphone, tethering

I often use tethering now that it's enabled on Softbank network in Japan.
I normally use WIFI connection. The thing is, my iPhone 5 is usually hard to discover from my computer (Macbook Air). Normally when I turn on the tethering and wait around 10 seconds, it shows up in the available networks in the computer. But after closing the computer, doing something else, than later (minutes, hours or days), without having switched tethering off on the iPhone 5, I don't think I was ever able to discover the iPhone 5 from the computer, without switching tethering on/off on the iPhone 5.
Sometimes even after discovery, the connection itself fails because of "timing out". ***It seems the tethering discovery with iPhone 5 is weak. Is this normal or an issue?*** Is the iPhone 5 faulty? (I know most/many iPhone 5 have really bad WIFI hardware and/or software. Maybe it's related.)
iPhone 5 is at iOS 6.1 I believe.

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but I have the same problems with my iPhone 4S. In fact, it's so bad that I often just resort to Bluetooth or USB which seem to be more reliable.

Comment: Ok when finally discovered and connected I don't experience any problems. I didn't feel any lost connections so far. It takes some patience with the connection. Then again I cannot tell how good/bad the transfer speeds are, but then again there's not much else of a choice. I cancelled a Pocket wifi subscription and now use tethering only when in the field. The discovery is my only concern at this point.

Comment: FWIW I also end up using a Bluetooth connection most of the time due to how often I'm unable to get a wifi connection to work for tethering.

Answer (score 1):

You should verify which software level you're on. 6.1 isn't available to the public yet. [iOS 6.0.2](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1621) specifically fixes a Wi-Fi bug (Apple doesn't say what the particular bug is, but it affects Wi-Fi). Check to make sure you're not on 6.0.1. If you are, upgrade to 6.0.2 and see if the problem is resolved.

Comment: Rechecked. I'm on 6.0.2. The 6.0.2 did not help my WIFI troubles.